# Shared data between clients in socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server

If I have class A and 2 threads from class B, and i want that thread to access to variable x in class A
if one of the thread manipulate in that variable, how the second thread get the last value of x resultant form first thread?

For example

```
public class A {
   public static int x = 0;
   public static void manipulate{
      x++;
   }
}
```

and class B for example:

```
public class B implements Runnable{ 
   public void run{
       A.manipulate();
    }
}
```

If I run 2 threads, the first will set x to 1, and the second set x to 2, is that true?
if not true,  how i do that?

Comment: You could just try it? Isn't that a lot of the fun of programming?

Comment: This example is flawed in a multi-threaded environment, and will result in undeterministic behaviour. I recommend going through a threading tutorial to understand why accessing common resources from different threads requires you to provide some form of synchronization to get deterministic results.